# Can we somehow ask OS to load particular folder in RAM?

Tags: windows, performance

I am thinking that hoe good it would be if I can load a particular folder in RAM because I know that this folder will be used in some processing.

Now Why do I want to prelaod data in RAM? because I think that when loading a folder it will may be sequential read instead but when process runs it will be a random read so can we get better performance by preloading data which our process may need later.

Comment: Copy it to a RAM Disk, maybe, though if it's Windows idk how to then discover what drive letter it got. Mac would be pretty simple, as it mounts under /Volumes with the name you assigned it.

Comment: Suppose I installed Visual Studio 2017 which I won'install on RAMDisk but I want to preload it

Comment: You really need to specify which OS. Also, do writes need to go to disk? If not under Linux you could bodge something together with a Ramdisk and symlinks or unionfs type soln.